# hadoop-Not able to run namenode without a format

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distributed-computing, namenode

I know that this question has been asked before,saw the following solution:

```
<!-- to be modified in hdfs-site.xml-->
    <property>

        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>

        <value>/home/hduser/hadoop/data</value>

    </property>
```

I modified my hdfs-site.xml file, also removed the contents of the temp directory.But still,without formatting the namenode,it dosen't start.
Also,should the path of the directory given in the value of the value tag be already existing?

Any suggestions what point am i missing in the above updation?

Comment: Are you getting any problem while formatting or you want to start without format..?

Comment: Start it without format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without formatting the namenode,it dosen't start
>   Blockquote

As mentioned [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop#Formatting_the_Namenode), you need to format the namenode.

> should the path of the directory given in the value of the value tag be already existing?

Yes. Both the namenode and the datanode directories should be present and most importantly should have proper permissions to HDFS user.